# AJax and minifier on Windows 2008 R2, do I install on the server side?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an application that runs fine on windows 2003 environment with Ajax panels, checking to see if when I move this applpication to a new windows 2008 server R2, would I need to install the Ajax toolkit and then the Ajax minifier?

Thanks,

Comment: Obtained the answer in another forum, is not required on server. Hope it helps.